# How to run Apache ACE devserver using Proxy

Tags: apache, proxy, proxy-authentication, apache-ace

I am trying to start Apache Ace devserver on my machine running on a corporate network that requires proxy authentication, but the server does not starts & it gives Connection timeout error.

Following  the instructions from the link http://markmail.org/thread/tgoovlkp4gnc3lw4, i modified the run.bat to include proxy server & port. But the request does not reaches the proxy server & again it gives connection timeout error. How to start Apache Ace Devserver using Proxy?

Comment: You should not need to do anything special. However, based on your description, it's very hard to point out where the problem might be.